# Google App Engine Launcher not running application

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I started using Google App Engine Launcher in Python. I have also installed Python 2.7 on my PC and confirmed the interpreter works.

When I click run on an application a yellow triangle with an exclamation mark appears next to the name. I have tried accessing the application on localhost:8080, but as expected nothing shows up.

This is my error code:

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\appinfo.py", line 1873, in LoadSingleAppInfo
    listener.Parse(app_info)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\yaml_listener.py", line 226, in Parse
    self._HandleEvents(self._GenerateEventParameters(stream, loader_class))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\yaml_listener.py", line 177, in _HandleEvents
    raise yaml_errors.EventError(e, event_object)
google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: Unable to assign value 'Hello-Udacity' to attribute 'application':
Value 'Hello-Udacity' for application does not match expression '^(?:(?:[a-z\d\-]{1,100}\~)?(?:(?!\-)[a-z\d\-\.]{1,100}:)?(?!-)[a-z\d\-]{0,99}[a-z\d])$'
  in "C:\Users\username\Hello-Udacity\app.yaml", line 1, column 14
2014-04-22 00:07:52 (Process exited with code 1)
```

Any ideas on what is causing this? Why is the application not running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error code indicates that your app id does not follow the allowed format.  Looks like you are not allowed to use uppercase letters.